# Server application crashing as soon as a client disconnects

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock

So i just programmed a simple multithreaded client server application using winsock2 and TCP.

Here is a quick summary of how it works:

The servers main-thread is in a endless loop accepting clients and then also adding them to the servers vector which holds every connected client like this:
(only adding in the important stuff for my question)

```
std::vector <Client*> clients;
while (true){
    clients.push_back(&Client(accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL), this));
}
```

When a new client connects to the server we basically create a new Client object with the socket of the new client and the server itself as parameters.

My idea was then to give every client its own thread so every client can send data at the same time.

```
std::thread tickThread;

Client::Client(SOCKET socket,Server* server) :
isConnected(true),
socket(socket),
server(server)
{
    tickThread = std::thread(&Client::tick,this);
}
```

The thread for the client then checks if the client sent something and then sends it to the server. It also checks wether the client is still connected.
void Client::tick(){

```
while (isConnected){
    errorHandler = recv(socket, receivedData, 255, 0);
    if (errorHandler == SOCKET_ERROR){
        disconnect();
    }
    else {
        //send received data to server
    }
}
```

If the client disconnected it tells the server to remove the client from the connected clients vector and then sets the "isConnected" bool to false so the thread can exit its function.

```
void Client::disconnect(){
    isConnected = false;
    server->removeClient(this);
}
```

This is how it's supposed to work, however as soon as a client disconnects again the server crashes with the error:

R6010 - abort() has been called

All debugging shows me is this as my error:

```
switch (_CrtDbgReportW(_CRT_ERROR, NULL, 0, NULL, L"%s", error_text)){
          case 1: _CrtDbgBreak(); msgshown = 1; break;
          case 0: msgshown = 1; break;
}
```

So yeah i don't really know whats causing this crash, however i suspect that it might be related to the thread using a function of the client that's basically being deleted as it is being removed from the client vector of the server.

And if this turns out to be the problem could you guys give me ideas for a better way of implementing every client having its own thread?

Edit: changed the vector error, however the crash still happens as soon as a client disconnects

Comment: `&Client()` evaluates to a pointer to an rvalue which is only possible if you are using a non-conforming compiler. Don't do that.

Comment: So i should use a normal vector instead?

Comment: `All debugging shows me is this as my error` Is that really all? Did you check the call stack? Did you try to encapsulate some piece of code with `try/catch`? Did you try to comment the `server->removeClient(this);` to see if it stops crashing?

Comment: Why do you have a vector of pointers? When is the `Client` object supposed to be destroyed? It's not clear why you're doing what you're doing, which makes it hard to tell you the right way to do it.

Comment: I'm assuming the Client object is getting destroyed as soon as the method "server->removeClient(this);" is called and the client objects is being removed from the vector. (as i dont save the clients anywhere else)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in this block of code:

```
while (true){
    clients.push_back(&Client(accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL), this));
}
```

`Client(accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL), this)` is an expression which generates a temporary `Client` object that is destroyed when the statement finishes executing.  However, you take the address of that temporary object and add it to your `vector`.

If you want to create `Client` objects and store pointers to them, you will need to allocate memory for them.  I would recommend using `std::unique_ptr` to manage them so that your `vector` claims ownership of their memory and automatically frees them if they are removed from the `vector` or the `vector` itself is destroyed.  Then your code becomes:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Client>> clients;
while (true){
    clients.push_back(std::make_unique<Client>(accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL), this));
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` requires C++11, though.  For pre-C++11 compilers, you would have to use `new` directly: `std::vector<Client*> clients;
while (true) { clients.push_back(new Client(accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL), this)); }` and be sure to manually `delete` each `Client` when you remove it from the `vector`.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it to using smart pointers now. However it still crashes when a client disconnects.

Comment: @Styxs Are you joining or detaching `tickThread`?  It's hard to see where your problem is without a complete example of your code, but `std::thread` must either be joined to the main thread or detached or else you will likely see crashes when the thread is destroyed.  See the documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: @Open I tried joining or detaching the thread multiple times, however as soon as the destructor of the client object is called the server crashes.

Comment: @Styxs Like I said, without a complete minimal example that reproduces the problem it's hard to determine where there may be problems.  Visual Studio has some great debugging tools, have you tried using them?  If you're getting a crash and are able to reproduce it in debug mode, there is a good chance that the callstack will point you directly to the problematic line of code.

Answer (score 3):

In this piece of code:

```
clients.push_back(&Client(accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL), this));
```

You are pushing an address of a temporary object into the container. When push_back() is done, the temporary object is destroyed, so that address is no longer valid. I wonder, what kind of compiler allows you to do this.

Comment: I would think many compilers would allow this. It is perfectly valid code at compile-time. It is just not safe code to run at run-time. The compiler does not assume what a pointer-to-a-temporary will be used for (at the time the pointer is taken, the temporary is still valid), and it does not know that the `vector` will be holding the pointer for a period of time longer than the lifetime of the temporary.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2013 and its compiler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, taking address of a temporary is an error. It is MSVC extension, which I find abhorrent. For instance, here is what g++ does:
main.cpp:7:5: error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'int'
    &(int(10));
    ^ ~~~~~~~
1 error generated.